# how to change default username of postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have tried to change the default username of postgres with this command :

```
ALTER USER postgres RENAME TO myname
```

but pgAmin responds me with this error :

```
ERROR: ERROR: session user cannot be renamed
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You shouldn't be using the superuser for regular work to begin with. Just create a new  (restricted) user with the name you want

Comment: how to create a new restricted user?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html